# Shall I use noindex for my redirected pages?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I had a lot of pages on my site with urls like `example.com/help/page-name`. Now I permanently redirect requests to those URLs to new URLs like `example.com/api/new-page-name`. I do this for a few months already.

The issue is: in Google Search Console I see older URLs in Page indexing -> Page with redirect list. It seems like there are some cyclic dependencies. For example, in the list I see now redirected page `example.com/help/A` which is referred to by now redirected `example.com/help/B`.

Shall I try using noindex for older, redirected pages? Shall I do something else?

Comment: If you noindex them google will then list them under "Excluded by ‘noindex’ tag," Use robot.txt they will be listed under "Blocked by robots.txt," 404 or 410 them and they will be listed under "Not found (404)" All-in-all having them be listed as pages with redirect seems to be the best place for the list, and then only take actions on the other ones ... maybe by redirecting them to put them into the ignore list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical advice is to keep redirects for as long as possible.

It can be worth auditing your redirects from time to time to make sure they directly end up on a working page.

e.g.

Update redirects that do several redirects before getting to the working page so they go directly.

Fix or remove redirects that end up on a missing page.